# Java Chart composer

Tags: java, swing, charts

In an application I am writing with java+swing - I have a set of database tables,
I would like to allow the user to generate charts based on selected columns (like in excel)

As this project is an academic project - I have no option to buy such a tool..
are there any good open source libraries that allow integration of such chart "designer" into my swing application ?

**EDIT**
I would like to clarify my question a little, 
I am interested in integrated Chart designer library and not a charting library like JFreeChart.

Comment: try jfreechart http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of nice Java libraries, like [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).

[Or you could look at one of these](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=swing%20charting%20libraries):

Comment: Thanks, but what i meant was that i need a chart designer - something like in excel where you select a chart type and columns  apply functions on those columns (avg sum etc) and this all reflects to a chart, i know that i can implement those stuff myself but it look so fundamental that i thought that maybe there is such library already exist.